# CSS: Why my image is not rendered?

Tags: html, css, firebug

I am using Jquery to add a `class` to a `div` like so...

```
somediv.addClass('correct').removeClass('wrong');
```

The CSS is as follows

```
.correct {
background-color: #CDF596;
border: 1px solid #75EE3B;
background-image: url('images/ok32.png') no-repeat right top;
}
```

The problem is that everything is rendered ok except the image that is not displayed at all.

After some firebugging i found that the line with the image is in strikethrough like so..

<s>background-image: url('images/ok32.png') no-repeat right top;</s>

What is going on here? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set `background-repeat` and `background-position` inside the `background-image` property. Either define the `no-repeat` and `right top` in their own properties, or use the `background` shorthand (in which case you should merge `background-color` into it and add `scroll` after `no-repeat`).

Comment: Thank you sir. I guess now i have to translate Chinese to English. I do not understand. Could you please post an example?

Comment: Instead of `background-image: url('images/ok32.png') no-repeat right top;` do this `background: #CDF596 url('images/ok32.png') right top no-repeat scroll;` Then get rid of `background-color: #CDF596`

Comment: Aha! Success! Thank you all. background: #CDF596 url('images/ok32.png') right top no-repeat scroll;

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle example of this? What Kolink said should work just fine. Are you sure the image path is correct? If the rule is canceled (strikethrough) there must be something that is overriding it somewhere...

Comment: @elclanrs Just had a success. I added the #color property to the sample you posted and also uploaded your comment! Thank you!